# Smart Install Maker does not support code signing?

Tags: installation, code-signing

Smart Install Maker does not support code signing? After code signing by `signtool.exe`, the file `setup.exe` created by Smart Install Maker is corrupted.

I appreciate it if you tell me your experience.

Answer (score 0):

No, S.I.M does not support signing, it has an internal CRC check procedure, and if you modify a single byte of the setup file, it will fail.

I have a payed license of that software, and they didn't give any support, it is like the software being abandonware, but an automate procedure is placed just to automatically accept the purchases. Maybe probably the original programmer just died or so?, no activity seen.

Oh - I am stuck in v5.0.2 or so. No a single mention about the issue in v5.0.4 changelogs.

Comment: Today, I tested the v5.0.4, it has the same problem.